# In Magit, the command `magit-status` opens the buffer with the status buffer. Is there some similar command to do the same but with the Slime's REPL?

Tags: key-bindings, magit, window, slime

I am using Emacs powered with Slime to write code on Common Lisp (SBCL). In addition, I am also using magit.

Magit has a **handy** command called `magit-status` (`C-x g`). I use it a lot and I tend to have 2 windows split horizontally on my screen. I would like to have a similar user experience with the Slime REPL's buffer.

Currently, what I do is: `C-x b`, then ido-mode shows the options in an augmented mini-buffer and, lastly, I start typing the REPL which is auto-completed.

I wish there was some command and a keybinding just like `magit-status` but to show show Slime's REPL buffer in one of the windows and move the cursor there.

Is this already available? What do I need to call?

If not, what should I do in my init file to have this shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `slime-switch-to-output-buffer`, bound to `C-c C-z` by default.

The SLIME User Manual has the documentation for this and many other interesting commands. You can read it inside of Emacs (use `C-h i` to open the Info viewer, you’ll find the manuals there), or online. See specifically [chapter 8.2 REPL: the “top level”](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/REPL.html).